# I can't move my family into Lakeview Manor! I think it's a glitch!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I have tried multiple things that don't work for some reason. I have loaded up a save before I bought the house, I have deleted and re-downloaded the Hearthfire DLC, but I still can't move my family, so nothing works! I think it's because I don't own the house. Will someone please help fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean "counted as my house"? What's not happening? Can you not build on it? Can you not get family to move in? Can you not get a Housecarl for it?

Comment: I cant put my family in it because there is some glitch that doesnt count my manor as a house i own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in your comments, you can't move your family. First, if you're having children, make beds and a container either on the upstairs floor on the left or in the bedroom wing. Make sure you also created a container for them to store too! Second, make sure you furnished your house. it doesn't need to completely be furnished, but it must not be a bit empty.

Comment: Well ill try but i have to have at least one thing in each room? Or what

Comment: @Benjaminward as I said, if it's completely empty, you can't move your family in. It doesn't need to be completely furnished. The important stuff is the containers, beds, and maybe some others stuff. The rest are optional.

Comment: But i have a house in whiterun, and the house im talking about now.. I look in stats and it says i still have only one house